# If statement in for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I've got a string list to iterate through with each line consisting `'is connected to'` or `'likes to play'` as a marker, it will only have one of them in each item of the list. So I used a for loop to iterate the list, and inside are the if statement to decide which phrase is in the item. The string list is something like this:

```
lines = ['a is connected to b','a likes to play guitar, trampolines','b is connected to m,z', 'b likes to play piano','c is connected to s','c likes to play video games, ball games']

def create(string_input):
    network = {}
    lines = string_input.split('.')
    for line in lines:
        user = {}
        if len(line)>0:
            name = line[0:line.index(' ')]
            if 'is connected to' in line:
                friends = line[line.index('is connected to')+len('is connected to')+1:].split(",")
                user['friends']= friends
            elif 'likes to play' in line: 
                likes = line[line.index('likes to play')+ len('likes to play')+1:].split(",")
                user['likes']= likes
            network[name] = user
    return network
print create(lines)
```

However, the result of print doesn't give me both `user['friends']` and `user['likes']`
The end result only contains data in the second if block, and all if 'is connected to' data were replaced with [] and lost. I'm not sure if the data structure or the if statement was handled incorrectly. Anyone can help me to see what's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

As David pointed out, the problem in the code lies in with updating the dictionary instead of the for and if statements. Thanks y'all!!

Comment: Where do you actually call the `create` function?

Comment: Hi Evan, it's called : print create(lines)

Comment: That isn't anywhere in your code pasted above. You should add all relevant details.

Comment: corrected, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using the split() function correctly. That will take a string and split it into an array, but you're passing in lines, which is already an array. Try removing `lines = string_input.split('.')`, since you already have a formatted array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lines = ['a is connected to b','a likes to play guitar, trampolines','b is connected to m,z', 'b likes to play piano','c is connected to s','c likes to play video games, ball games']

def create(string_input):
    network = {}
    lines = string_input.split('.')
    for line in lines:
        user = {}
        if len(line)>0:
            name = line[0:line.index(' ')]
            if 'is connected to' in line:
                friends = line[line.index('is connected to')+len('is connected to')+1:].split(",")
                user['friends']= friends
            elif 'likes to play' in line: 
                likes = line[line.index('likes to play')+ len('likes to play')+1:].split(",")
                user['likes']= likes
            network[name] = user
    return network

for line in lines:
    print(create(line))
```

Your code is good, you just need to pass in the strings in your lines list item by item. There are other ways to do this, but this is a simple one.

Hope it helps!

**Edit**

I I put the iteration in a main function because I could hear my CS prof scream in agony when I submitted by original answer.

```
def create(string_input):
    network = {}
    lines = string_input.split('.')
    for line in lines:
        user = {}
        if len(line)>0:
            name = line[0:line.index(' ')]
            if 'is connected to' in line:
                friends = line[line.index('is connected to')+len('is connected to')+1:].split(",")
                user['friends']= friends
            elif 'likes to play' in line: 
                likes = line[line.index('likes to play')+ len('likes to play')+1:].split(",")
                user['likes']= likes
            network[name] = user
    return network

def main():
    originalStrings = ['a is connected to b','a likes to play guitar, trampolines','b is connected to m,z', 'b likes to play piano','c is connected to s','c likes to play video games, ball games']
    for string in originalStrings:
        print(create(string))
main()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Actually, I need to have the data of network correct. The print statement is only for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The line `network[name] = user` is the problem. Look at the input lines 'a is connected to b', 'a likes to play guitar, trampolines'. When you process the first line, you empty the `user` variable and write the connection to it, then set `network[name]` to be equal to `user`. Then when processing the second line, you again empty the `user` variable and write the likes to it, then set `network[name]` to be equal to (the new) `user`, clobbering whatever previously existed in `network[name]`. So you only end up with the last line for each user being kept.

To fix this, replace `network[name] = user` with:

```
if name in network:
    network[name].update(user)
else:
    network[name] = user
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for for pointing it out. It indeed is the reason!

Answer (score 1):

You replace the dict user every time in the loop,and the dict lose the imformation before.Try this:

```
def create(string_input):
    network = {}
    lines = string_input.split('.')
    for line in lines:
        if len(line)>0:
            name = line[0:line.index(' ')]
            if name not in network:
                network[name] = {}
            if 'is connected to' in line:
                friends = line[line.index('is connected to')+len('is connected to')+1:].split(",")
                network[name]['friends']= friends
            elif 'likes to play' in line: 
                likes = line[line.index('likes to play')+ len('likes to play')+1:].split(",")
                network[name]['likes']= likes

    return network
```

Comment: Thank you Yi for the answer! Appreciated!